# MySQL checking if string exist and updating or creating

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

i am trying to make an simple `if exist` check for MySQL via php and then i will create an String if not exist; or if an string exist, i will update and add to the value `counter = counter + 1`

But now i dont now why nothing happend :s

What i am doing wrong --- i had search for the problem but i didnt has find anything..

thanks ahead

heres the code

```
$rankset = '';
$steamid64 = "76561198070477917";
$localmap = "de_dolls";

mysql_connect("localhost", "######", "###############") or die(mysql_error());  
mysql_select_db("server") or die(mysql_error());

$check1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `darkrp_missingmap` WHERE map = '$localmap'") or die(mysql_error());

while($info1 = mysql_fetch_array( $check1 )) 
{ 
  if(mysql_num_rows($info1) == 0) {
    print "existiert nicht wird erstellt...";
    mysql_query("SELECT server INSERT INTO darkrp_missingmap (map, count) VALUES ('$localmap', '1')");
  } 
  else {
    print "existiert wird aufgestuft...";
    mysql_query("SELECT server UPDATE darkrp_missingmap SET count = count + 1 WHERE map = '$localmap'");
  }
}
```

Comment: u need update statement here instead this SELECT server INSERT INTO darkrp_missingmap (map, count) VALUES ('$localmap', '1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, you can ref [[this]](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

```
$check1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `darkrp_missingmap` WHERE map = '$localmap'") or die(mysql_error());
$nums = mysql_num_rows($check1);

if($nums == 0) {
 // do something
}
```

Or you can use this sql.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM `darkrp_missingmap` WHERE map = '$localmap'
```

And get this query's result `count`.

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$nums = $row[0]['count'];
```

Answer (score 1):

[mysql_num_rows()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) takes a resource object as a parameter which is your `$check1` while you are passing an array `$info1` to it.

You should be doing:

```
$check1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `darkrp_missingmap` WHERE map = '$localmap'") or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($check1) === 0) {
    #no records found
    print "existiert nicht wird erstellt...";
    #rest of your code
} else if (mysql_num_rows($check1) === FALSE) {
    #query failed
} else {
    #records found
    print "existiert wird aufgestuft...";
    #rest of your code
}
```

You should be careful about using `==0` because `mysql_num_rows()` returns `FALSE` on failure which can also be loosely compared to `0`.

#### Note:

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: So why not show him the right way, if `==0` is wrong?

Comment: @SecondRikudo I would have wanted to do that but I wasn't 100% sure whether he is checking for query failure or no records. I could have assumed though with the print statement if it wasn't in a different language. Anyways, I think it's worth pointing out.

Comment: Google translate tells me that "existiert nicht" means "does not exists". So I am guessing that `===` is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think you select and insert at one time and you dont need that either 
try this

```
if(mysql_num_rows($info1) >0) {

print "existiert nicht wird erstellt...";
mysql_query("INSERT INTO darkrp_missingmap (map, count) VALUES ('$localmap', '1')");

} else {

print "existiert wird aufgestuft...";
mysql_query("UPDATE darkrp_missingmap SET count = count + 1 WHERE map = '$localmap'");
}
```

try this and tell

Comment: yeah i know i have tried some codes on phpmyadmin and yeah helpful this thing :) but always thankk you :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have found my trouble i have already select the db "server" and then i tried to make this
INSERT INTO `darkrp_missingmap`(`map`, `count`) VALUES ('zu_kotze', '100')

Here the working example:
    $steamid64 = "76561198070477917";
    $localmap = "de_dollsw";

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "####", "##########") or die(mysql_error());  
mysql_select_db("server") or die(mysql_error());
//maplog

$check1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `darkrp_missingmap` WHERE map = '$localmap'") or die(mysql_error());
$nums = mysql_num_rows($check1);

if($nums == 0) {
print "existiert nicht wird erstellt...";
mysql_query("INSERT INTO darkrp_missingmap (map, count) VALUES ('$localmap', '1')");
} else {
print "existiert wird aufgestuft...";
mysql_query("UPDATE darkrp_missingmap SET count = count + 1 WHERE map = '$localmap'");
}
```